# Nerve excitability and K+ concentration

Tags: neuroscience

My book says that the excitability of the nerve is increased when increasing the the potassium ion (K+) concentration in the extracellular fluid and vice versa.

I don't understand this mechanism could someone explain it for me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just for reference, what book are you speaking of?

Comment: my physiology book which my college provide.